How should I model my following database schema
I have a (possibly very beginner-like) question regarding the modeling of my database for a current project. The lecture hasn't helped me much so far, so I'm asking here
I am currently developing a system for managing bookings.
Each booking always has the following basic details such as
name: String 
email: String 
date: Date 

There are now different “booking types” in the system.
For simplicity, I will call them OptionA, OptionB, ...
The user now has the option of choosing between 0...n types, but also, for example, 2x OptionA and 1x OptionB in parallel.
This results in e.g.
[
 {
  "type": "OptionA",
  "someValue": 1
 }, 
 {
  "type": "OptionA",
  "someValue": 5,
  "anOptionalValue": "foobar"
 }
],
[
 {
  "type": "OptionB",
  "anotherField": "does not exist in OptionA"
 },
]

etc.
It becomes clear that OptionA has different fields than OptionB.
Now my question: how can I model my database in a way that it runs performant (for CRUD operation) on the one hand and is easily customizable and manageable for the future (e.g. if I want to add a new field for an option) on the other hand?
Currently I am thinking of one table for the general information and then one table per option. But what is the best way to refer to each option entry? A column in the general table that has an array on the foreign keys of the options? Or are there better ways, such as one column per option entry with a reference to the entry in the general table?
Since we haven't gotten that far in the lecture yet, I'm asking here and looking forward to feedback. Sorry if this question may seem very trivial to some, but it is complex for me.

No array of foreign keys, ever. Why not use a single table and add all possible columns? How many would that be?

Well, that would be way over 20+ columns, more to come. Also, this would lead to duplicated entries in the general information, e.g. name etc.

20+ sounds fine. You don't have to have duplicate columns. The "name" can serve all types.
